# Сan't pass selected row values ​from datagrid mui to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Im trying to update the value of the status or role of the user through the datagrid mui and save the changes by the save button, the id is passed, but the values ​​of the status and role fields are passed as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

data grid columns with onClick function

```
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "No", width: 100 },
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 200 },
    { field: "email", headerName: "Email", width: 200 },
    { field: "createdAt", headerName: "Created At", width: 200 },
    { field: "updatedAt", headerName: "Updated At", width: 200 },
    { field: "role", headerName: "Role", width: 130, type: "singleSelect", valueOptions: ["user", "admin"], editable: true },
    { field: "status", headerName: "Status", width: 130, type: "boolean", editable: true },
    {
      headerName: "Action",
      field: "action",
      width: 100,
      renderCell: (rowData) => (
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => updateStatusAndRole(rowData.id, rowData.status, rowData.role)}>
          Save
        </Button>
      ),
    },
  ];
```

function

```
  const updateStatusAndRole = async (id, newStatus, newRole) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/users/${id}/updateStatusAndRole`, {
        role: newRole,
        status: newStatus,
      });
      getUsers();
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `renderCell` function doesn't get the row data as a parameter but a ### object. To access the row data, use its row property, like this:

```
renderCell: (params) => (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => updateStatusAndRole(params.row.id, params.row.status, params.row.role)}>
        Save
    </Button>
)
```